# Convert weird characters in string to normal in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm crawling an html table with some Brazilian special characters, regretably when I get the string back the foreign characters are replaced by some weird code.

This:

```
São Paulo
```

Turns into:

```
S\u00e3o Paulo
```

Is there a built-in function to transform this weird characters back to normal?

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode('São Paulo')` returns `S\u00e3o Paulo`

`json_encode('São Paulo', JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)` returns `São Paulo`

If you're encountering this problem while returning a Model, you can use the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` in the following way:

```php
$user = App\Models\User::find(1);

return $user->toJson();

return $user->toJson(JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it's late to respond after two years, at least for my own sake and for the next time I need it, I'll write that the function worked excellently for me:

```php
mb_convert_encoding($string, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
```